# TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not tuple

Tags: python, sqlite

I received this error when trying to select columns from an SQLite3 DB, where the column 'Username' was the same as the variable 'username' and the column 'Password' was the same as the variable 'EncMessage' (Both the password and username was inputted by a user through a Tkinter entry box.

When I ran the program and inputted a valid username and password into the entry boxes, I received this error 'line 3139, in signin
c.execute(("SELECT Username, Password FROM Customers WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?", username, encMessage,))
TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not tuple'

Any help would be appreciated.

```py
# SignIn Function
def signin():
    username = user.get()
    password = pass.get()
    check_pass = password 
    
    reg = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!#%*?&]{6,20}$"
    
    # Compiling regex 
    pat = re.compile(reg)

    # Searching regex
    mat = re.search(pat,password)

    # Validation conditions
    if mat and password == check_pass:
        message = password 
        
        key = Fernet.generate_key()
        
        fernet = Fernet(key)

        encMessage = fernet.encrypt(message.encode())
        
        decMessage = fernet.decrypt(encMessage).decode()
        
        if check_pass == decMessage:

            conn = sqlite3.connect('CustomersTTA.db')

            # Create a cursor instance
            c = conn.cursor()

            c.execute("Select rowid, * FROM Customer")
            records = c.fetchall()

            c.execute(("SELECT Username,Password FROM Customers WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?", username, encMessage,))
         
            if not c.fetchone():
                messagebox.showerror("Invalid","Credentials are incorrect")
            else:
                print("Welcome")
```

Comment: Always post the whole error message with full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

```py
c.execute(("SELECT Username,Password FROM Customers WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?", username, encMessage,))
```

has double parenthesis, remove 1 layer.

Edit: Next time you ask questions, provide full traceback and tell us which line is it. You are making helping you harder than it should be.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this but it didn't work, I've managed to solve it myself now though.